# How can I customise the publish/edit screens, or provide a custom UI for editing entries?

Tags: channel-entries, control-panel

I'd like to provide my users a prettier UI to publish and edit/delete content (compared to what is provided by EE's control panel). For example, say I wanted to divide my entry form into tabs, etc. What are my options?

Comment: Can you clarify in your question if you are wanting to do this custom UI in the EE control panel or in a custom built "My Account" area in your templates?

Comment: A custom built "My Account" would be nice, if possible. Is it possible to allow users to interact with a custom theme instead of using CPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a custom "My Account" area in your EE templates to handle all editing of content. The primary addon you'd use is the [**Safecracker Module**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html).

Here are some global variable conditionals you'll use a lot with a custom "My Account" area:

- [{if logged_in}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#if-logged-in)
- [{if logged_out}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#if-logged-out)
- [{if member_group == ""}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#if-member-group)
- [{if member_id == ""}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#if-member-id)

There is also [**alternative syntax**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#alternative-syntax) for some of the above if you are trying to use the conditional inside a channel:entries tag... variable names get prefixed with "logged_in_"

Comment: I haven't used Safecracker, but will look into it. Can this also be used to provide member a customized member manager?

Comment: SafeCracker is for managing channel data so whatever you have stored in channels change be added/edited.

Answer (score 7):

You already can use tabs in your publish layout:

**Edit an entry > click "show toolbar" > add/remove tabs in this section:**

[image: create custom publish tabs]

More info in the EE documentation: [Publish Page Layouts](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish_page_layouts.html#tabs)

Comment: Yes - this is a very powerful tool that gets little love. You can move fields into different tabs, change field sizes and positioning, and make them available to some user groups and not others.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using an entry that uses Ajax calls via jQuery and SAEF. Basically just hold all the changes in a json string and pass them when everything is collected that you/they need.

I didn't use tabs though. I used modals and steps.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to customizing the layout of the publish screen [as per janvl's answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1488/55), you can have a look at one of the available [third-party themes for the control panel](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/filter?t=cpt).